# Why is jQuery-select2 autofocus not working and how do I fix it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 in all my projects and it works fine. But in my new project, my select2 input doesn't focus as it should. I have to click on it to focus. What can the  problem be and how can I fix it?

I don't know which part of code to show, because I didn't change anything in the standard select2 functions.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

After hard research, I found the reason and the solution on [a GitHub page](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/5993).

The reason certainly is that I'm using a new version of jQuery 3.6 in this project (others were built on v3.4).

The solution (it's enough to add this JavaScript code):

```
      $(document).on('select2:open', () => {
        document.querySelector('.select2-search__field').focus();
      });
```

Comment: This breaks when using more than one multi-select with tags (i.e. `$('.select2Tag').select2({tags: true,width: "100%",});`)

Comment: Lifesaver. It should be default behaviour anyway.

Answer (score 14):

updated answer for those who have multiple select, this way you will be  focus on the input field associated with the select field

```
$(document).on('select2:open', function(e) {
  document.querySelector(`[aria-controls="select2-${e.target.id}-results"]`).focus();
});
```

Comment: This give an error with jQuery 3.6.1 and select2 4.0.13: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'focus')`

Comment: @JulesColle make sure that the `<select>` field has a `id` attribute, that error basically tells you that document.querySelector cannot find the select2 input element

Comment: wow it worked like magic! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

I came up with a solution which is a mix of the different answers posted in the select2 github page (https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/5993).

Works with more than one select2 per screen and can also be used in combination with multiple-select2.

It just gets the search input from the OPEN dropdown (.select2-container--open), which is what we're aiming at.

Yep, It's a dirty workaround, but it's the only that works for me.

```
let forceFocusFn = function() {
  // Gets the search input of the opened select2
  var searchInput = document.querySelector('.select2-container--open .select2-search__field');
  // If exists
  if (searchInput)
    searchInput.focus(); // focus
};
    
// Every time a select2 is opened
$(document).on('select2:open', () => {
  // We use a timeout because when a select2 is already opened and you open a new one, it has to wait to find the appropiate
  setTimeout(() => forceFocusFn(), 200);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

The following solution worked for me with multiple select2.
I edited the solution by Kida:

```
$(document).on('select2:open', function(e) {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        document.querySelector('input.select2-search__field').focus();
    }, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Hey i had the same problem of `select2 autofocus search`. Before the fix i was using `Select2`  `4.0.6-rc.1` and `jQuery` `3.3.1`.

I updated `select2` version to `4.0.13` and `jQuery` to `3.5.1` the problem is solved on its own without using any additional scripts or triggering any select2 events.